# sitecore page editor change position actually deleting sublayout added on an item(Page)

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

I have a layout with two place holders leftColumn and rightColumn. For an item i am adding multiple sublayouts for leftcolumn and multiple sublayouts for rightcolumn. Now in page editor when i am trying to change position using "Change Position" button in toolbar and move content to another location, content is getting moved to my new location as desired. But when i click Save button on Ribbon, it is actually deleting moved content from presentation itself.

I am not sure why it is behaving like this. we are using Sitecore 6.4

Comment: Looks like a bug, you should probably contact Sitecore support.

Comment: What happens in the Sitecore content editor under Presentation > Layout Details for the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We opened a ticket with Sitecore and found out that this is an existing bug. They do not support movement of multiple controls/sublayouts within same placeholder on layout using PageEditor. We need to use multiple placeholder on layout and then we can change position of controls from one placeholder to another one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see anything through Sitecore Logs? It may have any errors or exceptions that are being generated.